# Python method returning immediate then executing code during reload (gunicorn)

Tags: python

A totally bizarre issue.  Very simple code.

Gunicorn/Flask web app.  External call comes in, executes everything just fine or so it seems.
I'm calling method from another class.  I am instantiating that class in my gunicorn method that's handling the request.  The method I'm calling returns immediately (it's returning True/False, returns True even though the code hasn't been reached).

I have gunicorn set to reload when code changes.  When I make a change in my code to cause a reload of the app, all of the calls to this external class fire off in order.. like they were queued.

The external class is using cx_Oracle and making database updates (once the reload occurs)

The first line of this external method is a print().  In my application logs, that line is never printed until the reload occurs yet the return value in that class is somehow returned because if I return False or don't return anything, the app throws an exception (as it should)

This code returns immediate.

```
@app.route("/mytest")
def test():
  myclass = MyClass()
  myclass.update()
  return "OK"
```

Calling it:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/mytest
[2018-01-01 23:05:30 -0600] [12160] [DEBUG] GET /mytest
[2018-01-01 23:05:30 -0600] [12150] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
OK
```

update method:

```
def update(self):
    returnVal = True
    print("=======================> HERE")
```

Reloading app with a file change:

```
[2018-01-01 23:05:50 -0600] [12183] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12183
[2018-01-01 23:05:50 -0600] [12160] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12160)

==> nohup.out <==
=======================> HERE
```

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Updated post with all of the detail I can share.

Comment: Calling the code in test() outside of Flask runs no problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this.

I run gunicorn in nohup.  When I run it nohup'd, the calls to the other class lock or act totally crazy (my words!).  When I run it without nohup (but still background), it works properly.

I'm now running gunicorn with --daemon --capture-output to capture stdout and background gunicorn instead of using nohup.  No longer experiencing the issue.